# Struggling with printing

Tags: python

Below is a program that's meant to calculate a percentage and print a message telling them what grade they received based on what percentage of their score was. problem is every time I run it I get the message:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
I'm incredibly new to python and would appreciate any help.

```
score = input("Please enter your score:")
percentage = float(score) / 50 * 100
print(percentage)

if float(score) <59.99:
    print("you have passed with " + percentage + "%" + " , and received a grade F")
elif float(score) >60 and float(score) <69.99:
    print("you have passed with " + percentage + "%" + " , and received a grade D")
elif float(score) >70 and float(score) <79.99:
    print("you have passed with " + percentage + "%" + " , and received a grade C")
elif float(score) >80 and float(score) <89.99:
    print("you have passed with " + percentage + "%" + " , and received a grade B")
elif float(score) >90 and float(score) <100:
    print("you have passed with " + percentage + "%" + " , and reveived a grade A")
elif float(score) <50:
    print("Score is greater than 50.")
```

update: thanks for the help it's running perfectly now, code below is for reference

```
score = input("Please enter your score:")
percentage = float(score) / 50 * 100
print(percentage)

if float(score) < 30:
    print("you have passed with ", percentage, "%", " , and received a grade F")
elif float(score) >=30 and float(score) <35:
    print("you have passed with ", percentage, "%", " , and received a grade D")
elif float(score) >=35 and float(score) <40:
    print("you have passed with ", percentage, "%", " , and received a grade C")
elif float(score) >=40 and float(score) <45:
    print("you have passed with ", percentage, "%", " , and received a grade B")
elif float(score) >=45 and float(score) <=50:
    print("you have passed with ", percentage, "%", " , and reveived a grade A")
elif float(score) >50:
    print("Score is greater than 50.")
```

Comment: Why do you do `if`/`elif`/`elif`... on `percentage`'s value and then top it off with comparing `score`? `score` is a `str` (direct return value from `input()`); as such if you want to compare it you have to cast it just like you did when calculating it into `percentage`. `elif float(score) < 50:`

Comment: Also at least in North America if you got an F you didn't pass...

Comment: And you can rewrite your code to use a dictionary of thresholds/grades to avoid the useless duplication of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 15

```
elif float(score) <50:
```

score is a string. So you need to do the same thing you did in line 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
# Python Program to Calculate Total Marks Percentage and Grade of a Student

print("Enter the marks of five subjects::")

subject_1 = float (input ())
subject_2 = float (input ())
subject_3 = float (input ())
subject_4 = float (input ())
subject_5 = float (input ())

total, average, percentage, grade = None, None, None, None

# It will calculate the Total, Average and Percentage
total = subject_1 + subject_2 + subject_3 + subject_4 + subject_5
average = total / 5.0
percentage = (total / 500.0) * 100

if average >= 90:
    grade = 'A'
elif average >= 80 and average < 90:
    grade = 'B'
elif average >= 70 and average < 80:
    grade = 'C'
elif average >= 60 and average < 70:
    grade = 'D'
else:
    grade = 'E'

# It will produce the final output
print ("\nThe Total marks is:   \t", total, "/ 500.00")
print ("\nThe Average marks is: \t", average)
print ("\nThe Percentage is:    \t", percentage, "%")
print ("\nThe Grade is:         \t", grade)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).